# JNDI binding a simple object vs. one create with ObjectFactory

Tags: java, jndi

Is there a difference if i bind an object to jndi vs if the object is created via an object factory ?

Concrete case : I want to bind ProxyDataSource

```
ProxyDataSource proxyDS = new ProxyDataSource();
ic.bind("MyDataSource",proxyDS);
```

But there is also possible to use :

```
JndiProxyDataSource proxyDS = new JndiProxyDataSource("MyJNDIDataSource",dataSource);
ic.bind("MyJNDIDataSource",proxyDS);
```

I looked into the implementation of JndiProxyDataSource and it implements Referenceable and it is created via an object factory.

So what would be the difference in these two ?

Comment: Now i am thinking that in case we might want to store information and to be retrieved later from JNDI...

Comment: There is no difference between binding an object and binding an object. What's the *real* question here?

Comment: I did not understand the dif. between binding and object that implements http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/resource/Referenceable.html and a binding a plain POJO